# What order should teaching experience be listed in a teaching dossier when applying for teaching jobs?

Tags: application, faculty-application

Should a teaching dossier list teaching experience in chronological order (starting with most recent) or should I order things by relevance to whatever I'm applying for?

I'm applying for a job which has listed teaching Calculus and Linear algebra as the primary expectation.

My more recent experience has been with Adult Basic Eduation which is not relevant to the posting, so my gut says not to emphasize this first.

Are my instincts correct?  Should I put my older work experience at the front?

Comment: In general, there are two approaches: chronological and thematic.  Also note that you can do some suppressing of minor items that don't seem relevant to the specific position.  However, you'll probably not want to suppress your current or most recent employment situation. // In a cover letter you can pull out and feature the key items from your CV as your primary selling points. // If you like, you might possibly be able to find a spin for the recent job, to paint it as bolstering your suitability for the position you're applying for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official standard, but chronological order is always easiest to follow. However, if you have a non-standard dossier, you could sort your teaching experience according to what is most important.

But the best place to emphasize your relevant experience is in the teaching statement.